# How to pass mule logger category dynamically

Tags: logging, mule, esb, log4j2

I am scenario where the loggers in a mule sub-flow should write to the same log file where the parent\main flow logs. The parent flow which invokes the sub-flow will be different but the log should write into the respective log file defined for the parent flow.

What I would be requiring here is a feature where I could dynamically pass the category value in a mule logger. I tried passing a flowVars using the mule expression in the logger category but It seems not effective (PFB).

```
<set-variable variableName="flow" value="com.cisco.flow1" doc:name="Variable"/><logger message="Inside the service  --- ${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}log4j-research.log" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" category="#[flowVars.flow]"/>
```

Could anyone suggest a way to address the above requirement?

Mule Version: 3.7.0

Regards
Arun

Comment: Referring Mule documentation for [logger component](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/logger-component-reference), Category shall be filled in form of String. We cannot fill it with MEL.
IMHO, in this situation I will directly set the Category with "flow" or "sub-flow" respectively. And for dynamic marking, I will put it as part of log message.